# Laravel: Certain record getting displayed by Dump and Die but not when trying to display on view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make it possible to display a certain record from my database, all of the other records from the table will work but one record.

```
Collection {#218 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => MenuItem {#219 ▼
      +table: "MenuItem"
      +primaryKey: "MenuItemCode"
      #connection: "mysql"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "MenuItemCode" => "fri"
        "Gerechtcode" => "ha"
        "SubgerechtCode" => "wh"
        "MenuItem" => "Frikandel"
        "Prijs" => "1.00"
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => MenuItem {#220 ▶}
  ]
}
```

You can see here that all the records are getting displayed, the one in particular I need to use in my view is MenuItemCode.

```
public function bestellingShow($Tafel)
{
    $bestelling = Bestelling::find($Tafel);

    $gerecht = MenuItem::all();

    $reservering = Reservering::find($Tafel);

    return view('bestelling')->with([
        'bestelling' => $bestelling,
        'gerecht' => $gerecht,
        'reservering' => $reservering
    ]);


}
```

This is my function used for what I'm trying to achieve. As you can see it retrieves all of the menuitems from the database and returns them with the view.

I'm expecting to make all of the records displaying inside my view, but instead of returning the MenuItemCode, it returns a "0" aka a null. What am I wrong?

I'm also using relations, but a kind of simular function I'm using is working using the same method.

Comment: Can you show the blade view where you are using the `MenuItemCode`?

Comment: @foreach($gerecht as $g)
                                                <option value="{{$g->MenuItemCode}}">{{$g->MenuItemCode}}</option>

                                                <input type="hidden" name="prijs" value="{{ $g->Prijs }}"/>
                                        @endforeach

Comment: Your input is of type hidden is that supposed to? because type hidden will not be displayed. You can use the element inspector to see if the hidden fields are added to the page